# Run small app from master app like MPL/HAGO

Tags: android

I am working on a app... which have one Master app and other small-app can launch from the master app and all small apps not show in app Setting or any where in device like **MPL/ HAGO** all Games download but not show any where and we can launch form master app, what is logic behind it apps install but now show any where in device and launch form Master App......

Comment: did you find any thing?

Answer (score 0):

The AndroidManifest.xml has not defined those Activity objects as displayable to the Launcher, therefore they don't appear with the other apps.

Yet the main app can directly call `startActivity` to any screen, including the "small-app"s